# What will happen if I forgot to release the object in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, memory-management, memory-leaks

Will it auto release when the user quit the application? or it will stay in the machine until reboot? Also, have Apple provides any tools for developer to check whether they release the object or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably everything related to the app will be destroyed when the app terminates. The memory leak affect the memory usage of your application. It uses up memory, it's bad practice and it may introduce bugs.

About the tool, if you are using xcode then check out the very cool integrated [Static Analyzer](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/features.html) on the same page.